# Google search filter on URL of links on a page

Tags: search-engines, google-search

Is there a way to search within a specific website for pages that contain links whose URL contains a certain search string?

For example:
- There is a website, `www.website.com`
- The website has a page `www.website.com/something.html`
- The HTML of that page contains `<a href="http://anywhere.com/example?page=3">link</a>`

How can I search for all pages within the website that contain links that contain "page" in the URL of the link?

Something like: `insite:www.website.com inlink:page`

I've found http://nerdydata.com/ which searches the source code of websites, but it does not allow the search to be confined to a specific website.

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved using below format

> key_word site:website.com

The above query will search for the keyword in www.website.com

Ex : **test site:wikipedia.com**

above will list test content available pages inside Wikipedia website